# Unknown constructor 'MyIdeaExtension.MyIdeaExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)'

Tags: visualforce, ideas

When following the steps on this page to make an example VF page with the Ideas Controller https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_pages_ideastandardcontroller.htm

I get the following error

**Unknown constructor 'MyIdeaExtension.MyIdeaExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)'**

Does anyone know how to fix this? My controller looks exactly like the example, as does my VF page... with "standardController="Idea" extensions="MyIdeaExtension"" in the apex:page. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Found part of the issue, although it leads to another error

In the docs for the extension it has

**public MyIdeaExtension(ApexPages.IdeaStandardController controller) { ideaController = (ApexPages.IdeaStandardController)controller; }**

when it should be using the ApexPages.StandardController for the argument in the constructor.

**public MyIdeaExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { ideaController = (ApexPages.IdeaStandardController)controller; }**

But then this gives me an error on the actual VF page saying

**Invalid conversion from runtime type ApexPages.StandardController to ApexPages.IdeaStandardController**

*If someone can successfully implement the example in the docs I linked, I would love to know.*

Comment: Did you save the class with the filename MyIdeaExtension? You should.

Comment: @DougB Yes, the name is the same MyIdeaExtension.cls

Comment: Can you post your whole extension and page please?

Comment: @BrianMansfield it was the exact same as the docs like I said in the post, and I just found the issue which I answer.

Comment: @BrianMansfield nevermind, that fix creates another issue which I've mentioned in my post, this is very frustrating.

Comment: "The IdeaStandardSetController and IdeaStandardController classes are currently available through a limited release program. For information on enabling these classes for your organization, contact your Salesforce representative." are you sure it has been enabled in your Org?

Comment: @DougB does that mean if my Ideas is working in my org, that those controllers may still not be enabled? If so I will look into that, thanks Doug..

Comment: Yes, Ideas have been around a long while but these controllers are new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The IdeaStandardSetController and IdeaStandardController classes are currently available through a limited release program. For information on enabling these classes for your organization, contact your Salesforce representative."

Have you checked with Salesforce that it is enabled in your Org?

Comment: I will look into this thanks. May be the issue. Do you know how I would check if its enabled myself?

Comment: I'm going to delete my answer because after a quick search, this seems like it's definitely the explanation. Nice catch!

Comment: @MikeNorthorp I suspect that the fact that your code is giving those errors suggests that it isn't enabled but I don't know any way to check without contacting SF. Good luck!

Comment: @BrianMansfield your answer made a lot of sense too, I hadn't heard of these new controllers before today. Every day is a school day! :-)

Comment: It wasn't enabled in the Org, had to contact Salesforce to get it enabled, thanks all!